# XCode crashes when running Unity project in Simulator

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, crash, xcode6, code-signing

Running XCode 6.1.1 and Unity 4.6.1 (free version)

I edited the Unity-Generated Xcode project so that Base SDK is "iOS 8.1", and Supported Platforms is "iOS".  Other than that, it is the same.  Each time I run the project, XCode asks me if I want the app to accept incoming Network Connections (really annoying btw), and then XCode implodes with the below, about a Code Signature being invalid with lldb.  I can't imagine I'm the only one out there with this issue, but Google has not helped me out with finding others with this issue.  So... not sure what's happening here.

```
Process:               Xcode [9062]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.1.1 (6611)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6611000000000000~4
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       810788292
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [9062]
User ID:               501

PlugIn Path:             /Users/gregory/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4763D685-8069-492C-AACD-210671E5A7DD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D574563E-8038-4C30-B88B-0FF3B1AF96F1/LaserLarry.app/LaserLarry
PlugIn Identifier:       ca.crescentdevelopment.LaserLarry
PlugIn Version:          1.0 (1.0)

Date/Time:             2015-01-27 12:05:28.662 -0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.1 (14B25)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        D4619ABC-7D43-9E17-7C12-7ECEBAE0D4CA

Sleep/Wake UUID:       2F24D97F-F4B6-42EC-BFE3-110FF9BA4544

Time Awake Since Boot: 59000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        24  <lldb.process.internal-state(pid=9138)>

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000032, 0x000000011b5fa000

kernel messages:
-1 sec              CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x11b5fa000): p=9062[Xcode] final status 0x3000200, denying page sending SIGKILL
-1 sec              CODE SIGNING: process 9062[Xcode]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x11b5fa000 from offset 0xed4000 in file "/Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4763D685-8069-492C-AACD-210671E5A7DD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D574563E-8038-4C30-B88B-0FF3B1AF96F1/LaserLarry.app/LaserLarry" (cs_mtime:1422389070.0 == mtime:1422389070.0) (signed:1 validated:1 tainted:1 wpmapped:0 slid:0)
```